# How to access exception thrown in failed Laravel queued Job

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a Laravel 5.2 `Job` and queuing it. When it fails it fires the `failed()` method on the job:

```
class ConvertJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, DispatchesJobs;


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // ... do stuff and fail ...
    }

    public function failed()
    {
        // ... what exception was thrown? ...
    }
}
```

In the `failed()` method, how do I access the exception that was thrown when the `Job` failed?

I understand I can catch the Exception in `handle()` but I wanted to know if it's accessable in `failed()`

Comment: Catch it dear lisa, dear lisa... catch it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you explain...do I catch it in `handle()` then re-throw for the `failed()` to be called? Can I access the exception in `failed()`?

Comment: If you have logs enabled (by default logged as file in `storage` folder, you can see the stack trace there

Comment: you catch it in handle(), and in your catch-block, you call failed(). and if you want to access the catches exception - well, just pass it as an argument. even an exception is just a variable.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann sure but there's no "official" way of doing it? Seems like I should be able to find out what the exception was in the `failed()` method, that would make sense. The whole point of the `failed()` method is to get rid of the try catch blocks in `handle()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work

```
public function handle()
{
    // ... do stuff
    $bird = new Bird();

    try {
        $bird->is('the word');
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // bird is clearly not the word
        $this->failed($e);
    }
}

public function failed($exception)
{
    $exception->getMessage();
    // etc...
}
```

I'm assuming you made the `failed` method?  If that's a thing in Laravel, this is the first I've seen of it.

Comment: No the `failed()` is called by Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#failed-job-events

What you're doing appears to be the only way but I wanted to know if Laravel passes or stores the exception while `failed()` is being called.

Comment: Nope, never used that.  But if you have x-debug, you could run that and see what variables are defined when it calls `failed`.  Or you could put `\Log::info( dd( get_defined_vars() ) )` in your failed function.

Comment: This failed method is automatically called by Laravel. And the whole purpose of this is we don't have to catch and failed it manualy in the handle.

Comment: is there any more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 9):

you can use this code :

```
public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    // Send user notification of failure, etc...
}
```

but it is available from laravel 5.3. version. For older laravel versions you can use some not elegant solutions like @Capitan Hypertext suggested.

Comment: I believe you can use `Throwable` instead of `Exception`, and that will also catch custom exceptions

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
   /**
 * failed
 *
 * @param  mixed $throwable
 * @return void
 */
public function failed(Throwable $throwable){

    dd($throwable);

}
```